# Handling different window sizes of a Windows 8.1 store app, Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am developing a Windows 8.1 Store app using Visual Studio 2012. I added a basic empty page to my project, see XAML below -

```
<Page
    Name="BlankPage"
    x:Class="Game.Views.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Game.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="White">    
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My question is when I try to re-size my app to different window sizes by docking it next to another Windows 8.1 app, the BlankPage doesn't re-size correctly. I see the 'white background' covers the full screen when my app is running by itself. However, when I dock it next to another Windows 8.1 app, the 'white background', appears in the center covering about 60% of the screen size allocated to it. I tried manually setting the Page size to the NewSize width in the Windows SizeChanged event handler in BlankPage1.xaml.cs, but that did not work.

Why won't my page cover the full area allocated to it? This used to work correctly when I created my Windows 8 app page derived from BasicLayoutAwarePage, but I am unable to get this to work correctly in Windows 8.1. Looks like Visual Studio 2013 handles this easily using the NavigationHelper APIs, but I did not find a way of easily handling this is Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Are you sure its a Windows 8.1 app? you need visual studio 2013 to develop 8.1 apps not 2012 and the LayoutAwarePage is not used in the new templates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263110.aspx

Comment: @dellywheel - I think you are correct. I am developing the app on Windows 8.1 and I can also run it on Windows 8.1. So, I assumed that my app was being built for 8.1, but from it's behavior it looks like it is a Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Store app need to be developed using Visual Studio 2013.

Although you can build and run Windows 8 apps on Windows 8.1 devices, they may not work correctly until you re-target your app to Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013.